# How to sort and order a dataframe by the similarity of its rows

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

```
df
         Beginning1 Protein2    Protein3    Protein4    Biomarker1
Pathway3     A         G           NA         NA            F
Pathway6     A         G           NA         NA            E
Pathway1     A         B           C          D             F
Pathway2     A         B           H          NA            F
Pathway4     A         B           C          D             E
Pathway5     A         B           H          NA            F
```

I would like to re-order the above dataframe (df) so that the pathways that share the greatest similarity in their proteins pathways (aka the greatest similarity in columns 2:4) are sorted next to each other.

To be more clear, I would like the output to look like this:

```
newdf
         Beginning1 Protein2    Protein3    Protein4    Biomarker1
Pathway6     A         G           NA         NA            E
Pathway3     A         G           NA         NA            F
Pathway5     A         B           H          NA            E
Pathway2     A         B           H          NA            F
Pathway4     A         B           C          D             E
Pathway1     A         B           C          D             F
```

How would one go about doing that?  I've tried variations including unique(df), but none have worked so far.

Also, while just ordering by the amount of non-NA characters would work for this dataset, the actual dataset I will be analyzing will have hundreds of pathways with the same amount of steps.

Comment: Don't post pictures of data. Keep your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you!  I am new to Stack Overflow and wasn't sure how to input my dataframe in the question.

Comment: Though not it won't work in all cases, you could use the base R `order` function to sort the data: `df[with(df, order(Beginning1, Protein2, Protein3, Protein4)),]` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `arrange` from the `dplyr` package. It will sort the data frame based on one or more columns. You can use `desc` to sort in descending order, as requested in your post:

```
> dplyr::arrange( df, desc(Protein2), desc(Protein3), desc(Protein4) )

   Beginning1 Protein2 Protein3 Protein4 Biomarker1
 1          A        G     <NA>     <NA>          F
 2          A        G     <NA>     <NA>          E
 3          A        B        H     <NA>          F
 4          A        B        H     <NA>          F
 5          A        B        C        D          F
 6          A        B        C        D          E
```

Note that `dplyr` operations do not preserve rownames, as they follow Hadley Wickham's [Tidy data definition](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) (In brief, rownames are undesirable because `R` expects them to be unique). You can use `rownames_to_column` from `tibble` package to keep track of your pathway identifiers:

```
> tibble::rownames_to_column( df, "Pathway" ) %>% 
       dplyr::arrange( desc(Protein2), desc(Protein3), desc(Protein4 ) )

    Pathway Beginning1 Protein2 Protein3 Protein4 Biomarker1
 1 Pathway3          A        G     <NA>     <NA>          F
 2 Pathway6          A        G     <NA>     <NA>          E
 3 Pathway2          A        B        H     <NA>          F
 4 Pathway5          A        B        H     <NA>          F
 5 Pathway1          A        B        C        D          F
 6 Pathway4          A        B        C        D          E
```

There's an equivalent `tibble::column_to_rownames` if you need to put the rownames back, but it is generally advisable not to.

Comment: Thank you!  That works with my smaller dataset.  I will try with my larger, more complicated dataset and get back to you!

Comment: And I will definitely look into arrange, @Wen!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Btw: In column `Biomarker1`, you input and output are miss matched , I corrected input `df` base on my understanding to get your desired output. )

```
df[is.na(df)]=''
df$ALL <- do.call(paste0, df[,2:4])
df=df[order(rev(df$ALL),rev(df$Biomarker1)),]
df[df=='']=NA
df$ALL=NULL
         Beginning1 Protein2 Protein3 Protein4 Biomarker1
Pathway6          A        G     <NA>     <NA>          E
Pathway3          A        G     <NA>     <NA>          F
Pathway2          A        B        H     <NA>          E
Pathway5          A        B        H     <NA>          F
Pathway4          A        B        C        D          E
Pathway1          A        B        C        D          F
```

*Input*

`df`

**

```
#             Beginning1 Protein2 Protein3 Protein4 Biomarker1
#    Pathway3          A        G     <NA>     <NA>          F
#    Pathway6          A        G     <NA>     <NA>          E
#    Pathway1          A        B        C        D          F
#    Pathway2          A        B        H     <NA>          E
#    Pathway4          A        B        C        D          E
#    Pathway5          A        B        H     <NA>          F
```

**

Comment: You mean mine or Artem Sokolov's solution

Comment: Both of your solutions work.  They give slightly different outputs with my larger dataframe, but both outputs increase the dataframes organization, which was what I was going for.